# Ansible - Switch to new inventory file during play

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook that calls roles to bootstrap some VM's.
There are 3 plays and after the fist play completes I need to change to a new inventory file.

Is this possible?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can use in memory inventory with https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/add_host_module.html.

An example with Google Cloud https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/gce_module.html

Comment: Sadly that won't work for me, the new inventory already exists, I just need to switch to it.

Comment: okay, and with differents groups you can not have one inventory file ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did this:

- Move the inventory file out of the way
- Symlink to the new inventory file
- Refresh the inventory
- Complete the playbook
- Remove the symlink
- Put the original file back